# How to check Whether sprite is touched, and delete it when collided with other sprite in cocos2d-android

Tags: android, cocoa-touch, sprite, cocos2d-android

To learn cocos2d-android game engine, i started developing game using this tutorial, http://dan.clarke.name/2011/05/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d-pt2-%E2%80%93-rotating-turrets/ and added 3 ships in order to make it more attractive and cannons fixed on to it, if fireball falls from the sky on ship, ship will be burnt and destroyed by keeping this as the concept did the coding, but when fireballs falls on the ship it isnt getting destroyed(deleted), i tried in many ways but could not get the solution can anybody tell why the ships is not destroyed please? here's my coding for it.

```
public void update(float dt)
 {
LinkedList<CCSprite> projectilesToDelete = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();

for (CCSprite projectile : _projectiles)
{
    CGRect projectileRect = CGRect.make(projectile.getPosition().x - (projectile.getContentSize().width / 2.0f),
                                        projectile.getPosition().y - (projectile.getContentSize().height / 2.0f),
                                        projectile.getContentSize().width,
                                        projectile.getContentSize().height);




    LinkedList<CCSprite> targetsToDelete = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();

    for (CCSprite target : _targets)
    {
        CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(target.getPosition().x - (target.getContentSize().width),
                                        target.getPosition().y - (target.getContentSize().height),
                                        target.getContentSize().width,
                                        target.getContentSize().height);

        if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect))
            targetsToDelete.add(target);
    }

    LinkedList<CCSprite> shipsToDelete = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();
    for (CCSprite ship : _ships)
     {
            CGRect shipRect = CGRect.make(ship.getPosition().x - (ship.getContentSize().width),
                                         ship.getPosition().y - (ship.getContentSize().height),
                                         ship.getContentSize().width,ship.getContentSize().height);


            for (CCSprite target : _targets)
              {
                    CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(target.getPosition().x - (target.getContentSize().width),
                                                                              target.getPosition().y -
                                                                            (target.getContentSize().height),
                                                            target.getContentSize().width,target.getContentSize().height);


                 if (CGRect.intersects(targetRect, shipRect))
                    {
                            shipsToDelete.add(ship);
                            break;
                    }
            }                      
     }

    for (CCSprite target : targetsToDelete)
    {
        _targets.remove(target);
        removeChild(target, true);
    }

    if (targetsToDelete.size() > 0)
        projectilesToDelete.add(projectile);

    for (CCSprite ship : shipsToDelete)
    {
        _ships.remove(ship);
        removeChild(ship, true);
    }
}

for (CCSprite projectile : projectilesToDelete)
{
    _projectiles.remove(projectile);
    removeChild(projectile, true);

    if (_shipDestroyed > 0)
    {
        _shipDestroyed = 0;
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(Gameoverlayer.scene("You Win!"));
    }
}
```

Comment: did u tried the sample code of dan clarke?

Comment: yes tried, its working fine, but i want to implement some more functions to it @user2078315

Comment: if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect))
            targetsToDelete.add(target); use the break point here and check in the debugging mode this condition will execute or not ?